# Nvidia always switiching to the AMD renoir

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have new laptop Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ACH6.  I installed Nvidia-470 version as it is proprietary and tested. Everytime, I  **reboot** laptop it is switched back to the AMD renoir. After that, my Steam games are lagging until I reload 470 driver again in *Software&Updates*.
I am using 5.15.0-051500rc7-generic Kernel.
How can I switch constantly to Nvidia graphics ?
Tried `sudo prime-select nvidia` and after reboot is back to AMD renoir.
Should I unninstall AMD renoir dedicated drivers /`amdgpu-uninstall` / ?
How to do it ? Or maybe is set in Bios...
Also posting some pics below.
Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

[image]
[image]

PS: I do not have addes any PPA: [image]

**...When I swich from Wayland to Xorg on logging screen, it's working. But I am not sure if it is not just temporrary again...?**
[image]

Comment: NVIDIA drivers are known to have problems with Wayland and don't work well.  If you can select XWayland they may work.

Comment: Thanks much. I noticed that option. Will try.

Comment: @Terrance
I have same problem, but can't find XWayland option. Can you please send a link where to find it?

Comment: @PrimozS I believe if it is missing you just need to install it.  `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install xwayland`